# Laravel Staudenmeir hasManyDeep Relations Setup Issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I can't setup my relations in laravel using staudenmeir package
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-dee

I have "ServiceLog" Model [with relation defined by belongsTo to "Tool" model]
I have "Tool" Model [with relation by belongsTo "ToolGroup" Model]

I need to access ToolGroup in ServiceLog Model.

recap: ServiceLog - many to one- Tool - many to many - Group

I try with

```
return $this->hasManyDeep(
'App\Entities\ToolGroup',
['App\Entities\Tool','tool_has_group'],
)
```

But I got error, because the query generated search for ServiceLog id in Tool table but it is the inverse.

Can you help me in understanding the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your models and relationships correctly,

`ToolGroup` → belongs to many → `Tool` → has many → `ServiceLog`

The tricky part is the many-to-many relationship between `ToolGroup` and `Tool`, but this is just another table.  In reality, the actual tables might look like this, though yours may be named slightly different:

`tool_groups` → `tool_tool_group` (pivot table) → `tools` → `service_logs`

Getting service logs for a tool group looks like this:

```php
// App/Entities/ToolGroup.php

public function serviceLogs() {
    return $this->hasManyDeep(
        'App\Entities\ServiceLog', 
        [
            'tool_tool_group',  // the pivot table between ToolGroup and Tool
            'App\Entities\Tool'
        ],
        [
            'tool_group_id',    // Foreign key on pivot table
            'id'                // Foreign key on "tools" table
            'tool_id'           // Foreign key on "service_logs" table
        ],
        [  
            'id',               // Local key on "tool_groups" table
            'tool_id',          // Local key on pivot table
            'id'                // Local key on "tools" table
        ]
    );
}
```

For the inverse, i.e. getting tool groups for a given service log, you just have to reverse the order of the intermediate table keys.  Assuming below:

`ServiceLog` → belongs to → `Tool` → belongs to many → `ToolGroup`

You can either create it directly,

```php
// App/Entities/ServiceLog.php

public function toolGroups() {
    return $this->hasManyDeep(
        'App\Entities\ToolGroup', 
        [
            'App\Entities\Tool',
            'tool_tool_group'    // the pivot table between ToolGroup and Tool
        ],
        [  
            'tool_id',           // Foreign key on "service_logs" table
            'id',                // Foreign key on "tools" table
            'tool_group_id'      // Foreign key on pivot table
        ],
        [
            'id',                // Local key on "tools" table
            'tool_id'            // Local key on pivot table
            'id'                 // Local key on "tool_groups" table
        ],
    );
}
```

or assuming that you already have [existing relationships](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep#existing-relationships) defined in the intermediate model, you can use the `hasManyDeepFromRelations` method:

```php
// App/Entities/Tool.php
public function toolGroups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\ToolGroup');
}

// App/Entities/ServiceLog.php
public function tool() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\Tool');
}

public function toolGroups() {
    return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->tool(), (new Tool)->toolGroups());
}
```